# Display a lot of informations in a navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm working on a project in Swift 1.2 with Xcode 6.4.

I have reached a point where I want to completely customize my navigation bar. The main goal is to display some user data that will constantly change. For that I need to have a bigger navigation bar where I  can have the possibility to add at least 6 label.

[image: Navigation bar]

I wanted to know if that was possible, and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code should be pretty easily adaptable by adding multiple subtitle labels. You can add a custom title view to your navigation bar like so:

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8k8S.png)

```
- (void)updateTitle
{
    if(self.hasAppeared) {
        UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 44)];

        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        titleLabel.text = convo[@"name"];
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Quicksand-Light" size:18];
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7;
        [titleView addSubview:titleLabel];

        UILabel *subtitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        subtitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        subtitleLabel.text = self.otherPersonString;
        subtitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        subtitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        subtitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Quicksand-Light" size:13];
        subtitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        subtitleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7;
        [titleView addSubview:subtitleLabel];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabel, subtitleLabel);

        [titleView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[titleLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [titleView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subtitleLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [titleView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(-3)-[titleLabel]-(-2)-[subtitleLabel]-(1)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
    }
}
```

However, you won't be able to alter the height of the navigation bar itself, and this content won't remain with the bar throughout the app anyways unless you recreate it. Any reason you just can't add it in a new view below the navigation bar?

Comment: Well if i won't be able to alter the height of the navigation bar, i guess the only option i got is to add a view under the navigation bar, but for some design reason i wanted to have everything in the navigation bar to have something more fluid